# Derivatives with different rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having trouble with this one problem that just deals with deriving. I can't seem to figure out how they got their answer. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

$
\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x^2+1)^3}
$

The answer is:
$
\frac{-2(x+1)(2x^2-3x-1)}{(x^2+1)^4}
$

I seem to get the wrong answer when using the quotient rule.

Comment: May you show your steps?

Comment: Probably a typo ! It should be $\frac{-2(x+1)(2x^2+3x-1)}{(x^2+1)^4}$

Comment: $\begin{align}
  & {{\left( \frac{f}{g} \right)}^{'}}(x)=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{{{g}^{2}}(x)}=\frac{2(x+1){{({{x}^{2}}+1)}^{3}}-3(2x){{({{x}^{2}}+1)}^{2}}{{(x+1)}^{2}}}{{{({{x}^{2}}+1)}^{6}}} \\ 
 & {{\left( \frac{f}{g} \right)}^{'}}(x)=\frac{2(x+1)({{x}^{2}}+1)-3(2x){{(x+1)}^{2}}}{{{({{x}^{2}}+1)}^{4}}}=\frac{-2(x+1)(2{{x}^{2}}+3x-1)}{{{({{x}^{2}}+1)}^{4}}} \\ 
\end{align}$

Comment: Yea, I kept wondering why I get 3x instead of -3x. Must be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use quotient rule:
$$\frac{(x^2+1)^3\frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^2-(x+1)^2\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+1)^3}{{(x^2+1)^3}^2}$$
Do the derivatives out and simplify the denominator:
$$\frac{(x^2+1)^3\cdot 2(x+1)-(x+1)^2\cdot 2x\cdot 3(x^2+1)^2}{(x^2+1)^6}$$
Factor out $2(x+1)(x^2+1)^2$ from the numerator:
$$\frac{2(x+1)(x^2+1)^2((x^2+1)-(x+1)\cdot 3x)}{(x^2+1)^6}$$
Reduce the fraction and simplify the numerator:
$$\frac{2(x+1)(-2x^2-3x+1)}{(x^2+1)^4}$$
Factor out a $-1$ from $-2x^2-3x+1$:
$$\frac{-2(x+1)(2x^2+3x-1)}{(x^2+1)^4}$$
Thus, it seems that your book's answer is wrong and it should be $+3x$, not $-3x$. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+(x%2B1)%5E2%2F(x%5E2%2B1)%5E3) also agrees with me on this.

Comment: Exactly! I was so confused on how they got -3x

Comment: @CarterHunt Wolfram Alpha is really helpful at checking textbook answers that might potentially have typos and it's saved me a lot of frustration from wrong textbook answers.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)= \frac{(x+1)^2}{(x^2+1)^3}$$

$$f'(x)= \frac{(((x+1)^2)'*(x^2+1)^3)-((x^2+1)^3)'*(x+1)^2}{((x^2+1)^3)^2}$$

Hopefully you can do the rest.

Edit: don't forget the chain rule when differentiating $(x^2+1)^3$

$$g(x)=(x^2+1)^3$$
$$g'(x)=3(x^2+1)^2*(x^2+1)'$$

Comment: This is wrong. It should be $(x^2+1)^3$ in the denominator of $f(x)$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak everything else holds true.

Comment: It's still wrong. You didn't fix all of the typos, which is even more confusing. Yes, you have the right idea, but it's typos and little writing errors like these that could've messed the original questioner up, so it's important that our answers don't have any. EDIT: OK, I fixed the rest of the typos for you, so your answer is good now.

Comment: Yes, I kept getting 3x instead of -3x.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

The problem being fixed (typo in the book), let me remember you a small trick which makes life much easier when the expression contains products, quotients, powers. It is logarithmic differentiation.

Consider $$y=\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x^2+1)^3}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(y)=2\log(x+1)-3\log(x^2+1)$$ Differentiate $$\frac {y'}y=\frac 2{x+1}-\frac{6x}{x^2+1}=-2\frac{2x^2+3x-1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$$ So $$y'=-2\frac{2x^2+3x-1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\times \frac{(x+1)^2}{(x^2+1)^3}=-\frac{2(x+1)(2x^2+3x-1)}{(x^2+1)^4}$$